# Facebook Api EVENT_ID/invited/USER_ID1,USER_ID2 how to add Personal Message?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to use new graph api for invite to events like,
EVENT_ID/invited/USER_ID1,USER_ID2 
But i couldnt find to add personal message.
Is there any way to add personal message to invitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to carry out two functions. One to add the user to the event then another (refer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) to issue the post of the message to the events wall.

You will require the publish_stream permission.

Hope this helps.